# Not able to get value from JSON object using AJAX call

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json

I have sample code for getting json value from servlet through Ajax call.
In success function I am getting response. It is showing  `Object     :   [{"userId":"dfeterter"}]` in console.

But I am not able to get value of userId

```
$.ajax({
    url: "Registration",
    dataType: "json",
    data: {
        jsonbhvalue: bhvalue,
        jsonuid: uid,
        jsonpassword: password,
        jsonfname: fname,
        jsonlname: lname,
        jsonmobile: mobile,
        jsonemailid: emailid
    },
    success: function(variable) {
        var obj = $.parseJSON(JSON.stringify(variable));
        console.log("Object     :   " + obj);
        console.log("cval     :   " + obj.userId)
    });
});
```

Comment: What is the purpose of `$.parseJSON(JSON.stringify(variable))` ?

Comment: `var obj = $.parseJSON(JSON.stringify(variable)); ` is unnecessary. jQuery automatically parses any JSON.

Comment: so what i have to do?\

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks To @RobertoNovelo.

You have to remove $.parseJSON as you are already setting JSON by ajax configuration. `dataType: "json"`
You need to use:

```
obj[0].userId
```

Your response is array of objects.

Comment: @AbhishekMahapatra. First remove `$.parseJSON()` line from your code. Then use `console.log(JSON.stringify(variable))` and tell us what you see. Because if your `obj` looks like `[{"userId":"dfeterter"}]`, then this solution shud work. Also print `console.log(variable[0].userId)`

Comment: "[{\"userId\":\"jswjsjsj\"}]"
 undefined

Answer (score 0):

That is because your object is an array. You should either use `obj[0]` or assign the array to a variable and then use its members

```js
objs = [{"userId":"dfeterter"}]

firstobj = objs[0]

console.log("Object     :   " + objs);
console.log("cval     :   " + objs[0].userId);
console.log("cval     :   " + firstobj.userId);
```

Comment: try removing the JSON.stringify part, use var obj = variable only since you already have json as a datatype in your ajax call